# How to detect(condition) if Query Layer Connection is failing?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, database, query-layer

I have a job (arcpy script) which relies on a query layer but it fails sometimes. It has to do with the query layer connection (the point where job fails randomly)- which is totally under the control of ORACLE team. I want to capture this to discuss with ORACLE team. What should be the right layer property to capture this?

Comment: Did you try [Layer.isBroken](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/)?

Comment: I am working on 10.0

Comment: Also, can I do anything about it? say add some wait time and try again (though users on the other side won't be happy with this- but waiting is better than breaking)

Answer (score 1):

I've run into some issues with a few different tools failing because of Oracle connection problems. The workaround has been to wrap whatever process is failing in a try...except block and call it again if needed.

```
def do_work(self, call_counter):
    if call_counter > 0:
        time.sleep(15)

    try:
        #do your query layer work here
        #return whatever results you need, if any
        return "it worked!"
    except:
        #log here if needed
        return ""

def __init__(self):
    work_output = ""
    call_counter = 0 

    while len(work_output) == 0:
        work_output = self.do_work(call_counter)
        call_counter += 1
```